# Fetch (PHP) array in (MYSQL) database and insert some php array data into JavaScript

Tags: php

I'm fetching an array and I would like to insert some of the data into two places in javascript but I don't know how to do it correctly, can someone please help me?

I'm fetching an array in PHP/MYSQL like so:

```
<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) { ?>

<?php
//I WANT TO LOOP THE BELOW CODE IN JAVASCRIPT SOMETHING LIKE THIS?: 
echo 'var point'.$count.'= new google.maps.LatLng('.$LAT.', '.$LNG.');'; 
?>

<?php
// I WANT TO LOOP THIS ALSO BUT IT IS AT THE END OF THE JAVASCRIPT CODE AND THERE IS CODE IN THE MIDDLE THAT I DON'T WANT LOOPED
echo 'var marker'.$count.'= new google.maps.Marker({draggable: true,raiseOnDrag: false,icon: image,shadow: shadow,shape: shape,map: map,position: point'.$count.'});'; 
?>

<?php } ?>
```

The JavaScript looks like this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function load(){

 //** START LOOP THIS IN PHP **//    
    var point1 = new google.maps.LatLng(44.8041322, -93.1668858); //LOOP THIS IN PHP
 //** END LOOP THIS IN PHP **//    

    var myMapOptions = {
    zoom: 5,
    center: point,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),myMapOptions);
    var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
    'marker-images/image.png',
    new google.maps.Size(40,35),
    new google.maps.Point(0,0),
    new google.maps.Point(20,35)
    );
    var shadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
    'marker-images/shadow.png',
    new google.maps.Size(62,35),
    new google.maps.Point(0,0),
    new google.maps.Point(20,35)
    );
    var shape = {
    coord: [27,0,30,1,32,2,34,3,35,4,36,5,38,6,39,7,39,8,39,9,39,10,38,11,37,12,33,13,34,14,34,15,33,16,32,17,31,18,27,19,28,20,28,21,27,22,26,23,22,25,23,26,24,27,24,28,24,29,24,30,24,31,24,32,23,33,22,34,17,34,16,33,15,32,15,31,14,30,14,29,15,28,15,27,16,26,17,25,13,23,12,22,11,21,11,20,12,19,8,18,7,17,6,16,5,15,5,14,6,13,2,12,1,11,0,10,0,9,0,8,0,7,1,6,3,5,4,4,5,3,7,2,9,1,12,0,27,0],
    type: 'poly'
    };

 //** START LOOP THIS IN PHP **//
    var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({draggable: true,raiseOnDrag: false,icon: image,shadow: shadow,shape: shape,map: map,position: point1});
 //** END LOOP THIS IN PHP **//

    }
    </script>
```

I just don't know how to loop the info two times, the var point1... loop that is on top is not really a problem but how do i loop the bottom part without looping all of the javascript

Comment: Please don't use the `mysql_*` functions as they are in the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: Please make a clear question. I am not going to read your code in order to understand the basics of the Q.

Comment: @Jelmer The basics of the Question is in the title already: Fetch (PHP) array in (MYSQL) database and insert some php array data into JavaScript  what more should I insert ?

Comment: @compcobalt `Fetch (PHP) array in (MYSQL) database and insert some php array data into JavaScript`. That's the title, no question mark or what so ever there. Just add the question in the body of you opening post. Nobody is going to answer your question if it's unclear.

Comment: @Jelmer I edited the question, Thanks for reading my question/problem and helping to make it better so that I may get an answer. Thx again.

Comment: It looks like (from what I can tell) that you basically have it mapped out. Is it not outputting what you want / expect?

Comment: @ethrbunny I just don't know how to loop the info two times, the var point1... loop that is on top is not really a problem but how do i loop the bottom part without looping all of the javascript.

Comment: @ethrbunny your question kinda made me explain my problem alot better, I will add the answer into the question also. THX

Comment: Are you just wanting to loop individual map marker values? Then add a secondary loop inside the main PHP loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below should work, then simply insert $point_str and $marker_str in the appropriate places after the while loop.

```
<?php 
$point_str = '';
$marker_str = '';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
    // define $LAT, $LNG, $count++
    $point_str .= 'var point'.$count.'= new google.maps.LatLng('.$LAT.', '.$LNG.');'."\n";
    $marker_str .= 'var marker'.$count.'= new google.maps.Marker({draggable: true,raiseOnDrag: false,icon: image,shadow: shadow,shape: shape,map: map,position: point'.$count.'});'."\n";
}
?>
```